# redux-form -- Set Value for a field via code?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm creating a customised component for my form.

What I want: after I click a certain location, in my onClick handler, I can set the corresponding value for the form field.

How to do that?

My current solution:

```
_onClick(value, evt) {
  const {field, dispatch} = this.props
  if(dispatch){
    dispatch({type: "redux-form/CHANGE", field: field.name, value: value, touch: false, form: field.form})
  }
}
```

it doesn't work yet.. but even if it works,  I feel this is kind of hack.

Any better solution?

Note: I also asked this question on the issue page for redux-form: https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/369

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is resolved

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been resolved.

Comment: You should tag a question as off-topic because it has been resolved. That's not how `off-topic` is supposed to be used. This shouldn't be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue resolved. It turns out that I should make my component compatible with Redux-Form, reference: http://erikras.github.io/redux-form/#/faq/custom-component?_k=qnjmi9

Comment: I would suggest closing this issue if it's *resolved*.

Comment: @jpierson I'm getting an upvote and my close request didn't vent through. I think for the purpose of reference for future developers, I'll just keep the question. (yes, and I'm aware that there's a `delete` button)

Comment: Just fyi, link now hits a 404.

Answer (score 15):

Redux Form 6

Inside the form component using [props](http://redux-form.com/6.2.0/docs/api/Props.md/)

```js
this.props.change('field_name', 'value')
```

Outside the form component using [Action Creators](http://redux-form.com/6.2.0/docs/api/ActionCreators.md/)

```js
import { change } from 'redux-form'

dispatch(change('form_name', 'field_name', 'value'))
```